# Azure Cosmos NoSQL RequestCharge higher than expected for Inserts

Tags: azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-sqlapi, azure-cost-calculation

Using Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos 3.3 we are **inserting** a message into our Azure Cosmos NoSQL database in batches:

```
foreach (var item in listOfItems)
{
        var task = container.CreateItemAsync(item, new PartitionKey(item.TimestampDate));
         tasks.Add(task
               .ContinueWith(t =>
                {
                       if (t.Status == TaskStatus.RanToCompletion)
                       {
                          cost += t.Result.RequestCharge;
                       }
                 }));
               }
         await Task.WhenAll(tasks);
}
```

FOr testing we ran 1 Item and 1000 items.  In each case our request charge is close to 30 RU to insert 1 4k item, e.g.:

```
[
        {
            "MessageContent": {
                "StationID": "12349902",
                "GenerationDeltaTime": "37919",
                "StationType": "5",
                "ReferencePosition": {
                    "Position": {
                        "latitude": 481687966,
                        "longitude": 163300265,
                        "quadtree": "020220220002002200"
                    },
                    "Confidence": {
                        "SemiMajorConf": 600,
                        "SemiMinorConf": 300,
                        "SemiMajorOrient": 0
                    }
                },
                "Heading": {
                    "Value": 1069,
                    "Confidence": "28"
                },
                "Speed": {
                    "Value": 833,
                    "Confidence": "50"
                },
                "LongitudinalAcceleration": {
                    "Value": 161,
                    "Confidence": "\n              102\n            "
                },
                "Curvature": {
                    "Value": 1023,
                    "Confidence": "unavailable"
                },
                "YawRate": {
                    "Value": 32767,
                    "Confidence": "unavailable"
                },
                "VehicleRole": "",
                "DriveDirection": "unavailable",
                "LogDeviceType": null,
                "FixedStationID": null,
                "MessageAction": null,
                "Time": null,
                "LocationGps": null,
                "LocationQuadTree": null,
                "CommunicationChannel": null,
                "MessageType": "CAM"
            },
            "id": "550fa5b4-f433-46d5-acc5-4d1f0a623916",
            "DeviceType": "Central",
            "TimestampDate": "04-07-2023",
            "header": {
                "version": {
                    "major": 1,
                    "minor": 1
                },
                "name": "sc3-management",
                "timestamp": "2023-07-04T09:44:15.066795Z",
                "uuid": "e9afff0b-5508-4ab7-9f46-a607e42f267d"
            },
            "message": {
                "uuid": "550fa5b4-f433-46d5-acc5-4d1f0a623916",
                "timestamp": "2023-07-04T09:44:16.312795Z",
                "direction": "Arx",
                "rx_device": "rsu001",
                "rx_location": {
                    "latitude": 48.171516,
                    "longitude": 16.3321347,
                    "quadtree": "120230113201332120"
                },
                "messageid": 2,
                "protocolversion": 2,
                "security": "Unsigned",
                "tx_device": "12349902",
                "tx_location": {
                    "latitude": 48.1687966,
                    "longitude": 16.3300265,
                    "quadtree": "120230113201332213"
                },
               *"hash": "XRa+ywxEQKMM2weQN7wPNK6q8rTrdQqdE85LXdM6aq0=",
                "message": [
                    {
                        "encoding": "Zxer",
                        "data": "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"
                    }
                ],
                "rx_device_type": "Rsu",
                "test_message": false
            },
            "MessageType": "CAM",
            "_rid": "a5ZuAKPbo5IBAAAAAAAAAA==",
            "_self": "dbs/a5ZuAA==/colls/a5ZuAKPbo5I=/docs/a5ZuAKPbo5IBAAAAAAAAAA==/",
            "_etag": "\"8000178a-0000-0c00-0000-64a3eaf00000\"",
            "_attachments": "attachments/",
            "_ts": 1688464112
        }
    ]
```

Note we do have a partition that chnages every day and will have about 8 million messages in each day.

The same RU costs are visible through portal for 1000 messages we get about 30RU each.

We have added an index that excludes the inner hash/message and have also tried removing the message altogether, we can never get below about 28RU.

If we query this object via portal we get 2.7kb and it costs 2.87RU.

I've looked here to estimate cost and get 7RUs for a 4kb insert: https://cosmos.azure.com/capacitycalculator/
[image]

**So why is the Insert RU cost so high?**

Comment: What is your **Indexing Policy** in the Container? Did you specify that in the calculator tool (you need to Sign-In)? The default indexing mode is **Off** on the calculator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to verify and optimize your **Indexing Policy**.

The calculator uses a Indexing **Off** by default. But your container probably has Indexing **Automatic/Consistent**.

If you set the calculator with Indexing Automatic and use your document as example (load the JSON) or use the number of properties (72), you get ~35RU which is similar to what you are getting on your operations:

[image: Indexing policy configuration]

[image: Calculator configuration]

[image: RU calculation]

If the Indexing is **Off** (default), then the RU is 7:

[image: Indexing policy off]

[image: RU calculation with off]

Make sure to [adjust your Indexing Policy](https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/cosmos-db/index-policy#indexing-mode) on your Container to fit your query and operational needs.

Comment: Thank you.  The key is, as Matias says, to Sign In (tiny link at top of calculator) and specify index properties.  Note we had removed two large properties from the index and it made negligible difference.  We should have tried going from 72 to 10!

Comment: Watch out, if your JSON sample has an array around the item e.g. [ { item } ] it looks like its counted as one property and under reports the index cost!